# Is it possible to FAX over broadband?

Tags: windows-7, broadband, fax

With the broadband enabled, to my surprise, my laptop has a phone number with which it can send and receive SMS. Now, would it be possible to send a FAX from the computer? It would be from a file or via a printer-like device-driver. Either is fine. The laptop runs Windows 7 64-bits if that makes a difference.

Comment: In order to be able to answer this, we have to know more about how it sends/receives SMS messages.

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "broadband"?  You mean you are tethering to your cell phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending a Fax without a fax number](http://superuser.com/questions/440451/sending-a-fax-without-a-fax-number), [How can I send a fax with Windows 7 connected on DSL?](http://superuser.com/questions/86758/how-can-i-send-a-fax-with-windows-7-connected-on-dsl?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 Not duplicate. The laptop HAS a phone number and it's not my cell number to be clear.

Comment: @psusi - Maybe they call it differently where you are. Here they say 'broadband' or 'wwan' which means my laptop is connected to a cellular network. In this case a 4G LTE one but it can also connect over 3G, so hopefully the solution applies.

Comment: @LPChip - No idea how it does it and it even surprised me! When I activate the broadband service I got a 'Welcome' message. I try to send from my cell to the laptop and from the laptop to the cell and it works. That's how I found out my laptop's phone number :)

Comment: Maybe the laptop has a SIM card inside?

Comment: @Darius - Yes. It is Micro-SIM in fact. That one I put it myself, so I know.

Comment: @itai You may need to check with your SIM Card provider to see if they allow faxing over the mobile number. Also on Windows 8 (and most likely Windows 7) there is an option to "Print" to a Fax.. have you tried that?

Comment: Print to FAX does not work but good suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to the provider, it is not possible. A phone number is just part of the way SIM cards identify themselves but, unless one has analog service too, faxing is not possible.